# Divergence theorem computation

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, divergence-theorem

[image]

The Divergence of the vector function comes out to be $4rcos(\theta$). The volume integral is thus:
$$\int_{0}^R\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2} 4rcos(\theta)*(r^2sin(\theta) d\theta d\phi dr)=\pi R^4/4$$

Now, for finding the closed surface integral $\oint_{s}\vec{v}.d\vec{a}$, we write:
$$\oint_{s}\vec{v}.d\vec{a}=\int_{1}\vec{v}.d\vec{a}+\int_{2}\vec{v}.d\vec{a}+\int_{3}\vec{v}.d\vec{a} +\int_{4}\vec{v}.d\vec{a} $$

Where $1$: the surface "bulging outward", $2,3,4$ are the surfaces (quarter-circles) in the $xy,yz,xz$ planes respectively.

Now, $\int_{1}\vec{v}.d\vec{a}=\int_{1}\vec{v}.(rd(\theta)rsin(\theta)d\phi\hat{r})=\int_{1}\vec{v}.(rd(\theta)rsin(\theta)d\phi\hat{r})=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}sin(\theta)cos(\theta)d\theta d\phi=\pi R^4/4$.

Which means, to "check" the divergence theorem , we need to show that $\int_{2}\vec{v}.d\vec{a}+\int_{3}\vec{v}.d\vec{a} +\int_{4}\vec{v}.d\vec{a} =0$.

However, I am finding this computation incredibly difficult, as the area vectors in these surfaces are pointing in the $\hat{k},\hat{j},\hat{i}$ directions, so we need to effectively convert between spherical and Cartesian coordinates.

Questions:

**1. Is there a "symmetry"/alternate argument to show: $\int_{2}\vec{v}.d\vec{a}+\int_{3}\vec{v}.d\vec{a} +\int_{4}\vec{v}.d\vec{a} =0$?**

**2. Am I misinterpreting the $\oint$ symbol in this context? Is it somehow *by definition* only $\int_{1}$?**

Comment: I think you should be able to show that the surface integrals should be zero over all the quarter surfaces.

Comment: @IshraaqParvez without converting between systems?

Comment: Plug in the equations for each of the planes in spherical i.e. $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\phi = 0 , \frac{\pi}{2}$ then reason out the direction of each of the spherical unit vectors on each of the planes, i.e. on the $xy$-plane $\hat{\theta} = - \hat{k}$

Comment: Yes, without it. Just shift the values of the azimuthal as they remain constant over each quarter. It then converts to a simple doble integral.

Comment: @IshraaqParvez the integrals on the quarter surfaces are not all $0$. Two of them specifically cancel out with each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your working, you are considering $\theta$ as the polar angle. I do not see it mentioned clearly in the question but if that is the notation used in the book and in the question, here is how the transformation would look -

$\begin{bmatrix} \hat{r} \\ \hat{\theta}  \\ \hat{\phi} \end{bmatrix}  = \begin{bmatrix} \sin\theta\cos\phi  &  \sin\theta\sin\phi & \cos\theta \\ \cos\theta\cos\phi & \cos\theta\sin\phi & -\sin\theta \\ -\sin\phi & \cos\phi & 0             \end{bmatrix}    \begin{bmatrix} \hat{x} \\ \hat{y} \\ \hat{z} \end{bmatrix}$

So to show that the flux through $3$ planar parts of the sphere in the first octant sum to zero -

i) For part of the sphere in $YZ$ plane in first octant, the outward unit normal vector in cartesian coordinates will be $(-1, 0, 0)$ and as $\phi = \frac{\pi}{2}, 0 \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2} \,$ for the surface, it will transform to $(0, 0, 1)$ in spherical $(r, \theta, \phi)$. The vector field will be $(r^2 \cos\theta, 0, -r^2\cos\theta)$.

ii) For part of the sphere in $XZ$ plane in first octant, the outward unit normal vector in cartesian coordinates will be $(0, -1, 0)$ and as $\phi = 0, 0 \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$, it will transform to $(0, 0, -1)$ in spherical. The vector field will be $(r^2 \cos\theta, -r^2, 0)$. As the dot product is zero, the surface integral will be zero.

iii) For part of the sphere in $XY$ plane in first octant, the outward unit normal vector in cartesian coordinates will be $(0, 0, -1)$ and as $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}, 0 \leq \phi \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$, it will transform to $(0, 1, 0)$ in spherical. The vector field will be $(0, r^2 \cos \phi, 0)$.

For $(i)$ and $(iii)$, you can either calculate and show or simply argue that the integral will be equal but with opposite sign and hence sum to zero.